# The Day Opened With

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the usage of the verb "open" in this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=K_dpBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=%22The+day+opened+with+a+blistering+artillery+bombardment+similar+to+that+%22&source=bl&ots=PH-ftKOYd5&sig=jE9WW8B-u7XmYxqqI7WgP4vf780&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOmq6fleTMAhXpx4MKHdKHDfMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20day%20opened%20with%20a%20blistering%20artillery%20bombardment%20similar%20to%20that%20%22&f=false):

> The day ***opened*** with a blistering artillery bombardment similar to that which had occurred against the 83rd and 80th Brigades.

Would replacing "***open***" with "***begin***" be more standard English?  If "***open***" as used in the example is correct, then how are "*the day* ***opened***..." and "*the day* ***began*** ... " different?

Comment: Yes. The original corresponds to “The day started with...” In my opinion, there's no discernible difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

I think *the day began* and *the day opened* are very similar in meaning. I don't think *open* is any more standard than *begin* here. With *the day opened*, there might be some slight connotation that we are referring to a certain time of day when these sorts of actions usually occur, e.g., shelling at dawn. *Opened* seems to imply a formality which *began* does not. For this reason, in my opinion, *opened* works a little better than *began* in the quote above; I believe there probably is a little ceremoniousness to artillery usage in old wars.

Comment: Also, "to open fire" is often used when someone begins to shoot a weapon. Whether the author was referring to that usage is unknown.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20day%20opened%2Cthe%20day%20began%2C%20the%20day%20started&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20day%20opened%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20day%20began%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20day%20started%3B%2Cc0), you might think that usage of "the day began" is quite common. If you look at individual usages, though, the story is quite different: most do not have the meaning that you are looking for. Here are some examples:

> There is no question that in the calendar used in the Pentateuch **the day began** with the sunrise.
>
> the great battle of **the day began** about noon
>
> when **the day began** to wear away...

Looking at actual usages of **the day opened**, a much greater proportion relate to the start of the day (dawn) or to the start of activities on that day. They usually concern either the weather or military matters, or in this case both:

> The day opened out with a very hot sun, and no firing was heard on the lines, nor shells from the mortars

Based on this, I think that **the day opened** is the more appropriate usage for a description of military activities.